# report $http error using airbrake in angular

Tags: angularjs, http-error, airbrake

I already configured airbrake to report error but it seems it doesn't report http errors. Hence I'm trying to connfigure it to do so. Here's my factory:

```
import AirbrakeClient from 'airbrake-js';

export let errorHttpInterceptor = ($q, CONSTANT) => {
  'use strict';

  let airbrake = new AirbrakeClient({
    projectId: CONSTANTS.AIRBRAKE_PROJECT_ID,,
    projectKey: CONSTANTS.AIRBRAKE_PROJECT_KEY
  });

  airbrake.addFilter((notice) => {
    console.log(notice);
    return notice;
  });

  return {
    requestError: (rejection) => {
      console.log(rejection);
      // do something on error
      airbrake.notify(rejection);
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    },

   responseError: (rejection) => {
     console.log(rejection);
     airbrake.notify(rejection);
     return $q.reject(rejection);
   }
  };
};
```

Then in the config:

```
let httpAuthConfig = /*@ngInject*/ $httpProvider => {
  'use strict';

  let errorHttp = $injector => { return $injector.get('errorHttpInterceptor'); };

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$injector', errorHttp]);
};
```

It seem to work only that I get `[object Object]` as the error on airbrake, no additional error detail or Backtrace. Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out that the server response wasn't in the format airbrake wanted it so I passed an error message built from the response into the airbrake notifier.

```
responseError: (response) => {
  console.log(response);
  airbrake.notify({
    error: {
      message: response.status + ': ' + response.data.error.general,
      name: 'HttpError: ',
      stack: ''
    }
  });
  return $q.reject(response);
}
```

It doesn't feel like the cleanest of solution but it sure works.

Answer (score 0):

Morgan from Airbrake here!
Since you are using angular have you tried adding `$exceptionHandler`?   The airbrake-js readme has an example in the angular section:

https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js#angular

```
mod.factory('$exceptionHandler', function ($log, config) {
  airbrake = new airbrakeJs.Client({
    projectId: config.airbrake.projectId,
    projectKey: config.airbrake.key
  });
  airbrake.addFilter(function (notice) {
    notice.context.environment = config.envName;
    return notice;
  });

  return function (exception, cause) {
    $log.error(exception);
    airbrake.notify({error: exception, params: {angular_cause: cause}});
  };
});
```

If you need any further help getting angular working feel free to email us at support@airbrake.io or send us an in-app message!

From,
Morgan

Comment: I have already done that for the $exceptionHandler factory, but it seems that http errors are not reported to airbrake.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the clarification!